# google_play_services_lib vs google_play_services.jar , What is the implemaintation difference ?

Tags: android, google-dfp

I am integrating google DFP ad engine. It was suggested in to add google_play_services_lib but it does not work lower than 2.3 android os . So I imported google_play_services.jar to my project. 
and changed manifest file version to constant 4132500 and it works

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="4132500" />`

But Please guide me the pros and cons of both type of implementation and internally how it works. But I need to support lower version android also.